# p:fileUpload method not fired

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a form with a p:fileUpload, and when I submit the form, all methods are not fired

This is my xhtml :

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
          <p:fileUpload value="#{uploadBean.file}" mode="simple" id="fileUploadId"/>
          <p:commandButton value="Envoyer ce fichier" process="@form" update="messages fileUploadId" actionListener="#{uploadBean.upload}"/>
</h:form>
```

my bean :

```
public void setFile(final UploadedFile file)
  {
    System.out.println("Dans le setFile");
    this.file = file;
  }

  public void upload()
  {
    System.out.println("Dans le upload");
    System.out.println("Fichier : " + file.getFileName());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
  }
```

my web.xml :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

In the trace, I have just :

```
Infos: Dans le upload
Grave: Réception de «java.lang.NullPointerException» lors de l’invocation du listener d’action «#{uploadBean.upload}» du composant «j_idt11»
Grave: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The method setFile() is not call...

Thanks

edit : 
All the code of my bean :

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UploadBean implements Serializable
{
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 556636819990963651L;

  private UploadedFile      file;

  public UploadedFile getFile()
  {
    System.out.println("Dans le getFile");
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(final UploadedFile file)
  {
    System.out.println("Dans le setFile");
    this.file = file;
  }

  public void upload()
  {
    System.out.println("Dans le upload");
    // System.out.println("Fichier : " + file.getFileName());

    FacesMessage msg;
    if (file == null)
    {
      msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Raté ! ", "Le fichier vaut null.");
      System.out.println("la variable file : null");
    }
    else
    {
      msg = new FacesMessage("Ouép ! ", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
      System.out.println("Le nom du fichier uploader est : " + file.getFileName());
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: The keyword I can pick up from your stack trace is `java.lang.NullPointerException`. I suggest you start from there and look for exactly what is being `null`.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes : It's my var "file".

Comment: can you delete the word `final` from your `setFile` method?

Comment: hmmm... the last problem I can think of is that you imported the wrong package for your Scope. Can you provide all the code of your `uploadBean`?

Comment: I have edited my previous post with all the code of my bean

Comment: Ok, sorry. I'll try to don't forget that ^^'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you provided, I think you have done correctly so far. However, there are still 2 things you need to take care of:

1. You need to download [common-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi) & [common-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/download_fileupload.cgi) and import the `.jar` file into your Library folder.
2. You also need to make sure that there are no other filters in `web.xml` or any classes that are annotated with `@WebFilter` which may read the `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()` before PrimeFaces's filter, because it can be read only once.

Comment: 1) I have download yet this two files (and imported in my library). 2) I have no other filter in my web.xml and I have no classes whitch read the `HttpServler#getInputStream()`... I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: With the code of PrimeFaces (unmodified) I can see in Firebug the file on the network, but it's don't call my methods. And if I add ajax, methods are call, but I don't see the file on the network tab in Firebug...

Comment: I tried testing your code and it worked on my side. I haven't figured out any other reasons why it does not work on your side.

Comment: Ok, Thank you.  I don't have any idea why it don't work on my side ^^'

Comment: On your side all it work... You have all (two) methods called (setFile and Upload) ?  With the same code, it work fine on your side and not on mine.  It's really strange...

Answer (score 1):

You are using prettyfaces too? Then try it (set dispatcher):

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the form was not submitted and the setters methods were never called, add

```
<f:ajax event="change"/>
```

inside the component what u want to submit. also

```
"immediate=true"
```

on the component itself. Thought might be helpful to others..